# Can my windows form detect if my console is closed?

Tags: c#, winforms

So it's like my windows form is ready to reopen the console window when the console is closed on it's own. My windows form is on the system tray.
I still can't figure out why the console is closed. The error is still unknown.

Comment: Welcome good sir.  Any code to show?  WinForms apps generally don't have a _"console"_

Comment: What exactly is your question/problem/error? Which console window of a windows application closing or opening it or opening it again after someone closed it or...

Comment: The winform is just for detecting the closed console. And the console is the main window

Comment: You can watch the process ID, Termination or you can find Window by Title

Comment: Whoa, I think I can use that idea @Tony. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can watch the process ID, Termination or you can find Window by Title:

```
foreach (var pList in System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses())
{
    if (pList.MainWindowTitle.Contains("Calc"))
    {
        var hWnd = pList.MainWindowHandle;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("FOUND: " + hWnd);
    }
}
```

Also give a look at [System.Diagnostics.Process](https://www.bing.com/search?q=C%23+System.Diagnostics.Process) and [FindWindow](https://www.bing.com/search?q=C%23%20FindWindow)